# How do I use the GNS 620 Trainer provided by Garmin?

Tags: flight-simulator, trainer

I downloaded the Trainer for the Garmin GNS 620 [here](http://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=9256).

I installed and now have a few programs. I can open the GNS 620, the touchscreen GPS and boot it up, plan a route and so on.

There's also a program to open the G600, the PFD and MFD. However, when I open this program, it just says it can't connect to a simulator and exits.

My questions is: How can I use those trainers properly? How can I simulate the flight? How do I control the virtual plane? Do I need a simulator for this?

I would really appreciate answers, as I have no idea what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Is there a manual installed with the software? Even if someone here knows the trainer well, explaining how to use a complex piece of software isn't really a good fit for a Q&A site like this.

Answer (score 4):

I found all the information needed in the "Trainer's User Guide.pdf" that was installed with the software.

In short, launch ONLY the `GTN - G600 Trainer`.  Do not have any other components started.

3 windows should launch: **GTN Trainer**, **G600 Trainer** and **Navigation Control**.

Give it a good 30 seconds to load up, then on the GTN Trainer window, click "Power On".
All windows should come up and be active.